# I want to simulate Google Places using my company's installations

Tags: google-maps

I'm attempting to create an app that will let the user know which 5 or so of our 1,000+ locations he is closest to.  I've looked through the Places docs (since Places appears to provide similar functionality), but have not found exactly what I'm looking for, or if I have, I haven't recognized it as such.
I assume I'd have to pass the user's current location, along with a list of all of our installation locations, unless there's a way to have Google persist our installation locations which I could reference with each call.
If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar questions: [Closest of a list of addresses from a location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451831/closest-of-a-list-of-addresses-from-a-location) and [Google Map get 10 closest Points of all Markers on a Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352950/google-map-get-10-closest-points-of-all-markers-on-a-map)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in a crow flies type closest then you don't even need maps at all.

You just need the long lats of the position of the user and of the various offices and do a straight forward distance calculation between them.

```
          $sql = "SELECT *,(((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin((`Latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos((`Latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- `Longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) as distance FROM `MyTable` WHERE distance <= ".$distance.";//** Miles **//
```

That's a sql string to get all within a certain distance.

To get the five closest you would simply have an 'order by' and 'top 5'